# gvim search query for mixed AND & OR conditions

Tags: gvim

Hi I want to search text inside gvim with the following criteria 
`a&b&(c|d)`.
I know for `a&b` it is `/.*a\&.*b` and for `c|d` it is `/c\|d` but combining these two doesnt work.
what can be the exact command ?

edit: I tried `.*a\&.*b\&.*(c\|d)`, but it is taking it as `.*a\&.*b\&.*(c` ORed with `d)` , inc brackets.

edit2: breaking the expression to `a&b&c`|`a&b&d` is working,`.*a\&.*b\&.*c\|.*a\&.*b\&.*d` , but thats not something I am looking for.

Comment: What, exactly, have you tried?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: damned. no answer yet !

Comment: You might as well post that as an answer: it might help somebody else, and you might get some reputation from it (if people vote for it).

Comment: @G-Man I dont know the answer.

Comment: I mean the `.*a\&.*b\&.*c\|.*a\&.*b\&.*d` workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, [vim search patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern) are interpreted
with `\&` binding tighter than `\|`
(i.e., `\&` has higher precedence than `\|`),
and there does not seem to be any way of overriding  that. 
However, the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) says that

> (P∧(Q∨R)) ⇔ ((P∧Q)∨(P∧R))

where “∧” represents AND (i.e., `\&`) and “∨” represents OR (i.e., `\|`). 
Substituting

- P = a&b
- Q = c
- R = d

we can derive that

> a&b&(c|d) = (a&b&c) | (a&b&d)

so you can do the “a&b&(c|d)” search
with the regex `.*a\&.*b\&.*c\|.*a\&.*b\&.*d`. 
Of course, this is not ideal.

**Note:** This solution was identified by the OP.